# Cant't recognize touch on iOS, but on Android and Mac it's ok

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to deploy my Unity app on the iPhone, but there is a problem. I have one scene, where you are clicking on objects and the objects playing sounds after click. Everything is going just fine on the Android device and the Mac, but on iPhone it seems like it's not listening to the touches on the screen. I have tested this on the iPhone 4G, iPhone 5S and iPad air 3, all with the same results.

This problem occurred yesterday, before that it was fine on all tested platforms.

What might the problem be?

Comment: If it was fine before, but no longer works, what did you change. And if you can't pinpoint it, show us your relevant code by updating your question.

Comment: yeah, code would be nice, theres a chance i think you are using onMouseDown instead of GetTouch, onMouseDown will work on android and mac but it wont work for ios